# Why doesn't my cookie authentication work in asp .net core?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I have enabled authentication using cookies:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebBasic.Core.Controllers;

namespace WebBasic.Core
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddMvc();
      services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(AuthController.AuthControllerAuthId);
      services.AddAuthorization(options => { options.AddPolicy("IsFoo", policy => policy.RequireClaim("FooType")); });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
    {
      app.UseMvc();
      app.UseAuthentication();
    }
  }
}
```

...and created a generic view to test claims:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebBasic.Core.Controllers
{
  [Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]
  public class AuthController : Controller
  {
    public const string AuthControllerAuthId = "AuthControllerAuthId";

    public IActionResult Test()
    {
      var claims = string.Join(", ", User.Claims.Select(i => i.Type));
      return Ok($"{User.Identity.IsAuthenticated}: {claims}");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthFixed()
    {
      var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim("FooType", "FooValue", ClaimValueTypes.String)};
      var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
      var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
      await HttpContext.SignInAsync(AuthControllerAuthId, userPrincipal);
      return Ok("ok");
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
      await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(AuthControllerAuthId);
      return Ok("ok");
    }
  }
}
```

When I get `/api/auth/authfixed/` a cookie set:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 05 Sep 2017 13:57:39 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Kestrel
Set-Cookie:.AspNetCore.AuthControllerAuthId=...; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly
```

...but when I return to `api/auth/test` I get:

```
False
```

ie. I am not authenticated? The authentication middleware is not picking up my cookie? Why not?

If I add `[Authorize]` I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.<ChallengeAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
```

??? Why do I need to explicitly set that?

I know, I can set DefaultChallengeScene, DefaultAuthenticationScheme and DefaultScheme to `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, but all that *actually does* is set to the string 'Cookies', and it still doesn't work.

What's actually happening here?

Comment: Have you tried to put `app.UseAuthentication();` before `app.UseMvc();` in `Configure` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone else who has this problem, the trick is that all your components need to refer to the same identity id.

In my case, I was using `AuthControllerAuthId` as my custom auth identifier, instead of the default `Cookie`. What I needed was to make sure all parts of the auth chain were using this value.

When adding authentication:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
  {
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = AuthController.AuthControllerAuthId;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AuthController.AuthControllerAuthId;
    options.DefaultScheme = AuthController.AuthControllerAuthId;
  }).AddCookie(AuthController.AuthControllerAuthId)
```

When constructing the `ClaimsIdentity`:

```cs
var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, AuthControllerAuthId);
var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
```

When signing in:

```cs
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(AuthControllerAuthId, userPrincipal);
```

Everything was actually working, but specifically in my case, the trick is to look at the `AuthenticationType` on `User.Identity` and ensure that it is correctly set at all steps.